# How to count no of student got registered for a particular course for the below two given table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9z4VB.jpg)Here I have to write an SQL query in order to count the number of students registered for a particular course by taking the 
`"examseriesname"` as user input from User Interface.
I am using Mysql Query browser:

The following are the different table details:

```
CREATE TABLE tblcourse (
  courseid NUMERIC(8) PRIMARY KEY,
  cname    varchar(20),
  uid      NUMERIC(8),
  numberofyears NUMERIC(8),
  coursecode Varchar(8)
);

CREATE TABLE tblstudent (
  regid NUMERIC(8) PRIMARY KEY,
  sid   NUMERIC(8),
  sname varchar(20),
  year varchar(4),
  courseid NUMERIC(8),
  branchid NUMERIC(8),
  uid NUMERIC(8),
  collegeid NUMERIC(8)
);

CREATE TABLE tblexamseries (
  id NUMERIC(8) PRIMARY KEY,
  monthandyearofexam date,
  examseriesname varchar(20),
  serieslastdate DATE,
  chalanlastdate DATE
);
```

Comment: We would but, we don't know where to start..could you provide what you tried so we can work some advice for you from there?

Comment: provide please tables DDL, data example and expected result of query

Comment: Are you really using both MySQL and Oracle here? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: I Just need one SQL query which should produce the result like: 
sl.No          cname        noOfStdReg
01                B.tech        1200
02                BCA            850
03                B.SC           4587

Sorry, i am not getting any idea for the sql query. so based on the provided table data please write one sql query which will form the result as above output.

Comment: @Milan I've updated the question with DDL representing your text description - please check and modify if there are any errors. Also, you will need to add in the foreign key relationships as it is unclear how `tblexamseries` relates to the other tables.

Comment: I think you need to show some example data.. because tblexamseries doesnt seem to tie up with anything else.

Comment: @MT0 Thanx a Lot Sir For Your Most Valuable Effort. Here tblexamseries is not having any relation with other table. i need to write the java logic in such a way.... that if user choose the "ExamSeriesName" then it Will Show the list of "courseName and NoOfStdRegisted" for it.  So based on this requirement i need 1 SQL Query to write in java DAO logic.

Comment: How can anyone write the logic if the table you are referencing does not to relate to the the tables you want to select from?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry yesterday i have not mentioned about the other two table. Today Sir told what should be the correct query so i am sharing that ans with you all.
Thanks For Your Support.

SELECT
   cname, COUNT(*)

```
FROM
          tblstudent st,
          tblstudentdetails sd,
          tblstudentexamregistration tes,
          tblcourse tc
```

WHERE

```
                tes.studentid=sd.id
                 AND
                sd.regid=st.regid
                 AND
                st.courseid=tc.courseid
                 AND
                tes.examseriesid='" + examSeriesId + "' 
                AND
                st.collegeid='" + collegeId + "' 
                GROUP BY
                tc.courseid  ;
```